# Push messages to clients in Python

Tags: python, real-time

How can I implement a system that can "push" messages to clients when necessary?
Basically, what I need is the ability to "push" text to Python clients from a Python server. The text will then be parsed to actions that will take care at the client side (I already know how to do this thing, once an 'action-text' is received).
I can check every couple of seconds for new 'action-texts' that are waiting -- it's just I don't think it's reliable and scalable to thousands of clients. The real-time thing is very important here.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I tend to lean toward Twisted for that kind of job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest having each client establish a socket connection to the server.  Each client can run a thread that attempts a blocking read from the socket (put it in a background thread) that pulls information off the socket when it's available.  Then, whenever the server writes to that socket the client should get it immediately.  The client's connection should subclass `telnetlib.telnet` imho, because it provides a convenient `read_until` method.  Something like this maybe:

```
class RPCConnection(object, Telnet):
  def __init__(self, host = 'localhost', port = 9198, auto = True):
    Telnet.__init__(self)

    self.host, self.port, self.connected = host, port, False

    if auto:
      self._connect()

  def _connect(self):
    self.open(self.host, self.port)

    self.connected = True

  def _disconnect(self):
    self.close()

    self.connected = False

  def _send(self, dict):
    self.write(json.dumps(dict))

  def _recv(self):
    resp = self.read_until('\n')

    try:
      return json.loads(resp)
    except Exception, e:
      print e
      print resp
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use redis publish subscribe model [more here](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

[Redis](http://redis.io/) is highly scalable and fast.

Example: (From https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/tests/pubsub.py)

```
import redis
import unittest

class PubSubTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.connection_pool = redis.ConnectionPool()
        self.client = redis.Redis(connection_pool=self.connection_pool)
        self.pubsub = self.client.pubsub()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.connection_pool.disconnect()

    def test_channel_subscribe(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.subscribe('foo'),
            ['subscribe', 'foo', 1]
            )
        self.assertEquals(self.client.publish('foo', 'hello foo'), 1)
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.listen().next(),
            {
                'type': 'message',
                'pattern': None,
                'channel': 'foo',
                'data': 'hello foo'
            }
            )
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.unsubscribe('foo'),
            ['unsubscribe', 'foo', 0]
            )

    def test_pattern_subscribe(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.psubscribe('fo*'),
            ['psubscribe', 'fo*', 1]
            )
        self.assertEquals(self.client.publish('foo', 'hello foo'), 1)
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.listen().next(),
            {
                'type': 'pmessage',
                'pattern': 'fo*',
                'channel': 'foo',
                'data': 'hello foo'
            }
            )
        self.assertEquals(
            self.pubsub.punsubscribe('fo*'),
            ['punsubscribe', 'fo*', 0]
            )
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting Redis rather than implementing your own socket stream